# List available roots in PSProvider

Tags: powershell

I can create a new PSDrive like that:

`New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Root hkey_classes_root -Name HKCR`

But I need to know the name of the `Root`. Is there a way to list all available roots for given provider? `Get-PSProvider` only shows already mounted drives.

Comment: Get-PSDrive -PSProvider registry | select name, root

Comment: @DavidBrabant But it only lists roots of already mounted drives.

Comment: Are you talking about the Registry Roots?

Comment: @Luke No, I'm talking about any available provider.

Comment: Okay I am a bit confused by your question, can you explain a little more background, what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Luke I want to list all available roots for a given provider, no matter if a drive is mounted or not. E.g. for Registry provider, it would be HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_USERS, HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG.